# C#- triggering mouse and keyboard movements

Tags: c#

1. Is it possible to capture/trigger mouse or keyboard events inside an Internet Explorer browser tab?
2. How do I access the clipboard data of the browser?
3. How to manipulate the DOM of the page?
   Does a mechanism exist which will work across all IE versions?

Comment: I guess, you will have to write some kind of browser plugin to do all of that.

Comment: @Mitch - yeah they are three questions but kinda related to the same aspect 

@shahkalpesh - I know that but am looking for some specific commands or processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To capture you can use SetWindowsHookEx() with MouseProc() and KeyboardProc():
   **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990**
   To trigger look at SendInput function():
   **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310**
2. You can access clipboard through Clipboard class, here some examples:
   **http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial188_Clipboard-Copy-and-Paste-with-Csharp.html**
   **http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/clipboard01.aspx**
3. What do you mean 'manipulate'? 
   If you want to input some text, and press some buttons in IE window you can try to use UI Automation or Microsoft Active Accessiblity:
   **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788733.aspx**

Comment: Mihail- Thanks for the answer -
For the 3rd - When i mean manipulate I mean how to display small panel inside the page (which is obviously not an alert message since it makes the page to lose focus we require this panel to show error message that could happen at sender/receiver side because of problems in incompatibility produced by Resolution/OS/BrowserType/BrowserDisplaySize/BrowserPageAreaSize/SupportedMouseEvents/SupportedKeyBoardEvents/PluginMissmatch(like flash/silverlight)/ExtraMenusItemsOnRightClickBecauseOfAdditionalPlugins/MenuItemsOfBrowser

Comment: Try to look at IHTMLDocument2 Interface -- it gets information about the document, and examines and modifies the HTML elements and text in the document. May be it is what you needed?..